# Test management tool (MTM/TFS or HP ALM) integration with Gitlab, Jira, TestComplete

Tags: test-management

My company uses Gitlab for code check-in, Jira for bug reporting, and TestComplete for automation. We are looking for a test management tool that will integrate with our existing tools. The choice is between ALM and MTM.

I need to be able to define test cases and test suites in the tool, and link them to our automation. Once everything is connected, I need to be able to run the automation from the tool and view the results in the tool without having to do any manual steps.

The tool also needs to be able to integrate with Jira and Gitlab

**Is this possible with MTM or ALM?**

If it is possible, what are the pros and cons?

Comment: Voted to close as the answer will be primarily opinion-based.

Comment: Editing to make less opinion-based